# Scale cpu frequency in CLI?

Tags: command-line, cpu-frequency

I am using `cpufreq` to scale my CPU frequency. But I do that by clicking cpufreq icon on the panel of Ubuntu 12.04.

If without a mouse, how can I show and scale CPU frequency by running commands in terminal?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120328/how-to-set-the-cpu-freq-in-linux/120371#120371

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `cpufreq-info` - Utility to retrieve cpufreq kernel information. It will list available frequency steps, available governors, current policy etc.
- `cpufreq-set` - A tool which allows to modify cpufreq settings (try e.g. `cpufreq-set -g performance` or `cpufreq-set -f 2 GHz` once you know what frequencies your CPU can be set to)

You can also retrieve information about you cpufreq state directly from `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq` directory. For example available frequencies are stored in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies`.

Comment: thanks. (1) I found that I have not installed cpufrequtils. but I have `indicator-cpufreq ` running on the panel of the desktop for me to change by mouse. (2) Can I modify `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed` for changing the frequecy?

Comment: Yes, you can do that instead of `setfreq-set`, at least works for me.

Comment: Is it weird that I have installed `indicator-cpufreq` without installing  `cpufrequtils`? Does the former not depend on the latter? What do the two depend on, `libcpufreq0`?

Comment: @Tim - look at the package mgmt for this info.

Comment: jimmij, is it a good idea to put the change of cpu freq into  some file the OS executs when it starts? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163005/where-can-i-put-settings-that-are-run-with-root-and-last-from-start-of-os-till-i

Comment: I don't think any `rc` script from system start-up will be executed when system is waking up from `pm-suspend`. It sounds reasonable what peterph wrote there in the comment.

Comment: Hi jimmij, I have two cores on my laptop called CPU 0 and CPU 1 in the output of `cpufreq-info`. `sudo cpufreq-set -f 1.60 GHz -c 2` reports error, `sudo cpufreq-set -f 1.60 GHz -c 0` and `sudo cpufreq-set -f 1.60 GHz -c 1` don't change my cpu freq to `1.60 GHz` although there is no error.

Comment: And which values are present in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies`?

Comment: `2667000 2666000 2133000 1600000 800000`, and how can I scale both cores, and scale just one? I will be notified, only when you write "@Tim". Thanks.

Comment: @Tim Try `cpufreq-set -f 1.60GHz -c0` and `cpufreq-set -f 1.60GHz -c1`. Note missing space between frequency and metric prefix. At least this way it works for me.

Comment: WOrks. But only one core at a time? can all cores at a time?

Comment: @Tim I think it is impossible. There is `-r` flag for `cpufreq-set`, but according to manual `-f` works only with `-c`. You should be able to write to `/sys/.../cpu*/...` devices with one line/command if this is the point.

Comment: verbatim from current "man cpufreq-set": ... allows you to modify cpufreq settings without having to type e.g. "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_set_speed" all the time. -- so it is a "mere shortcut" (which is why the panel might not depend on the cli tool to be installed)