# Where can I put settings that are run with root and last from start of OS till it shuts down?

Tags: startup

Where can I put settings that are run with root and last from start of OS till it shuts down?

One requirement is that when I suspend/hibernate my Ubuntu 12.04 and wake it up, the settings should not be changed again.

For example, I would like to set [the cpu frequency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162887/possible-not-restore-cpu-frequency-after-suspending-and-waking-up) and the battery charge range. What commands can i put into the files you recommend for the above question?

Comment: Is there any particular command that you are trying to run? The only way I could think of is using a `watch` command inside `/etc/rc.d`.

Comment: some command like these? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162884/674

Comment: Suspend systems usually have hooks where you can attach whatever you like - check documentation from your suspend system (probably `pm-utils`?).

Comment: `rc.local` can be used but not best practice also if ubuntu still uses upstart  make a `foo.conf` file in `init.d`

Comment: why is rc.local  not best practice?  @jgr208

Comment: @Tim I am not sure but my one co worker who has been in industry for 15+ years with embedded and linux system said when I did that on one part of our project that it isn't.

Comment: http://bencane.com/2011/12/30/when-its-ok-and-not-ok-to-use-rc-local/